pull stuck in Sourcetree (git, github)
When I'm trying to pull from repo, the dialog keeps stuck with progress bar animating and never ends. I'm able to fetch without problems.
I used the verbose option and it seems like it's actually done...

What could be the problem / how do I figure out what is wrong? I don't have this problem when using console git.

What is your Git version? git --version ?

I recommend to copy the output (text) instead of copy the screenshot (image) which contains the text [or code] only.

git 2.47.0.windows.1
I'm on Win10

Could be a problem with 2.47.0, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/79078235/7976758 . Try to downgrade to 2.46.

thanks @phd - that was the issue indeed

As phd mentioned - the problem turned out to be git 2.47.0
After uninstalling it and installing 2.46.2 everything works fine.
